# Trying to monitor a number of remote MySQL connections

Tags: c#, java, .net, c++, python

I'm trying to monitor a number of remote database connections.

How can I constantly monitor a GMail account for routing emails based on their header within the same application?

This will need to be standalone or basic package.

Should I build a Qt or .NET app for this?

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are asking here.  Try asking each question as a separate SO Question, and try giving more detail about what you are trying to do.  Also, your poor choice of tags is not encouraging people to pay attention to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to constantly monitor the account then you'll probably want to use an IMAP package for this, such as Python's [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html). A tutorial which should help you read the header information is available [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-Email-Libraries-part-2-IMAP/3/).

Your question doesn't include enough information about what graphical functionality you want in your project to give a good suggestion for which GUI toolkit to use.

If this is a Gmail specific project, you might even consider using the [Gmail API](https://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/) and develop your application as a Gmail sidebar gadget.